# Laravel firstOrCreate with advance functions

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am stuck at one situation where i have to insert record only if composite columns values are not exist with given user id; something like

```
UsersInvited::firstOrCreate([
                            'invited_by_id'=>$eventDetails->user_id,
                            function($query) use ($thisEmail,$thisPhone){
                                return $query->where('email',$thisEmail)->orWhere('phone',$thisPhone);
                            }
                        ]);
```

If user_id =3 is inviter of event and some members are not registered in portal then they have to preserve in one table so that in future if invited user will install the app then i have to make it event member automatically.

Any other user can also invite the same members multiple times.

So in above case i wants to check that thisEmail = abc@gmail.com is invited by user_id = 3 or thisPhone=8945454545 is invited by same inviter then no need to make entry.

Is it possible in laravel - eloquent firsOrCreate ()?

Answer (score 0):

Using the code to get the method firstOrCreate():

```
public function firstOrCreate(array $attributes, array $values = [])
```

Hence: you can not append extra query parameters to this method.

In your case, you should try and find the matching record yourself. If it doesnt exist, you can create one. For example:

```
$attributes = ['invited_by_id' => '..'];

$instance = Model::where($attributes)->where(..)->orWhere(..)->first();

if( is_null ( $instance ) ) {
  $instance = Model::create($attributes);
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: `firstOrCreate()` is actually builder method, so you can call `firstOrCreate()` instead of `first()` and remove `is_null()` check.